Google Maps API onClick event: how to reduce the debounce delay for multiple or fast clicks?
I have implemented the regular strategy for getting the onClick event on the google maps api:
map.value.addListener("click", (event) => {
  onClick(event);
});

This works well for most of the time. It gets the click event only when clicking on the map and returns me useful data like the lat/lng. For what I've read, this is not just a regular domListener event, so the google maps api itself has it's own implementation for firing this event.
My problem is that it seems that this click event has some kind of debounce delay. If I click on the map, let's say, three times, really fast, the event only fires twice. It seems to me that it has some kind of 300-500ms delay after each click. The regular DOM click event, on the other hand, fires after every click, but I can't use it on the map given that it won't give me any lat/lng data, or another event data. The same delay happens with overlay clicks.
Oh, and btw, I'm not using double-clicks, and have disabled them through the disableDoubleClickZoom option. I suspect this delay on the regular onClick event happens to prevent it from being confused with double clicks. But, given that I've disabled them, that shouldn't matter anymore.
Is there any way to change this click event delay?
Here are my dependencies so far:
  "dependencies": {
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.16.8",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
    "@mdi/js": "^7.4.47",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.12",
    "nuxt": "^3.13.0",
    "nuxt-quasar-ui": "^2.1.6",
    "quasar": "^2.17.0",
    "vue": "^3.5.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.58.1",
    "sass": "^1.72.0"
  }


Consider providing a demo to debug. You're describing it like some known problem, but it's not. But it's reasonable for clicks to have some kind of a delay if other interactions like dragging and double clicks are supported, like in the case of GM. Also consider explaining your case because this could be XY problem that interferes with  these interactions

I've found the answer and it seems to be pretty straightforward. All I had to do was to listen to the mousedown and mouseup events, those will fire on every click and also return the lat/lng. The same events work on the overlays as well. Also, I now have much more control given that I can distinguish between left and right clicks and what to do between the press and the release of the button.
